# how to create the future meeting conversation using the Skype-for-Business-UCWA-PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, skype, skype-for-business

I am working on scheduling the meeting the using this git repository 
https://github.com/wapacro/Skype-for-Business-UCWA-PHP
by using this repository i am only able to create conversation please suggest if there is any way to schedule a meeting in skype for business . below i have mention the code of creating conversation .

```
require( "lib/base.ucwa.class.php" );
$ucwa = new UCWA_init( "http://myapp.example.com" );
$ucwa->getAccessToken( "some.user@yourdomain.com", "P@ssw0rd!" );

$im = new UCWA_use();
$im->registerApplication( "My Application" );
$im->createConversation( "sip:another.one@yourdomain.com", "Subject" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The library in its current form does not have the capability to create a meeting nor join a meeting**.  This would require additions to the library to store/expose the Href called [startOnlineMeeting](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-startOnlineMeeting) and you would also need logic to handle the events around for adding participants, [addParticipant](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-addParticipant).

You can get an idea for where to add the variable that would store the value of startOnlineMeeting by looking at line 84 of [use.ucwa.class.php](https://github.com/wapacro/Skype-for-Business-UCWA-PHP/blob/master/lib/modules/use.ucwa.class.php) where they have created a variable to store the conversation link.

Events are handled inside of the function waitForAccept inside that same file, but would need some rework as it is not generally focused on handling all event data returned from the Event channel, but for observing when the convesation is accepted.